# Convert vector image to raster image in Java

Tags: java

What seemed like a simple task at first turns out too hard even to Google. As the only search results I get are the opposite, converting "raster to vector", which is not what I'm looking for. The only other search result I get is some web service, which I also don't need.

The idea sounded pretty great: we store a vector image in .ai format so that we have a perfect reference image, and then convert it to .png or .jpg of any size for any purposes. Ideally this should be done without any middle-man web service, because the images are somewhat confidential.

Is there a way to do that in Java? Has anyone done that?

Comment: If you can display the image, you can rasterize it. At the lowest level, you can do a pixel-to-pixel copy, or work the rendering logic for your image in the first place into your "rasterizing" (though these steps should more or less be the same)

Comment: If you had an SVG you could easily do that with Batik, but .ai is proprietary stuff and doesn't seem to have any good tool support. Can Illustrator export to SVG?

Comment: @Taschi I have not idea actually. The initial requirement is .ai. I will look into it.